Sparse Packing for CKKS
Let $N$ be a power of two integer and $n$ be a divisor of $N$. We can encode a vector in $\mathbb{C}^{N/2}$ into the polynomial ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^N+1)$ as described in the original CKKS paper using the canonical embedding (i.e. evaluation at primitive $N$-th roots of unity). Now let $z\in \mathbb{C}^{n/2}$. Sparse encoding as described in the CKKS bootstrapping paper is a way to sparsely encode this $z$ into $R$.
I can understand that the decoding procedure is almost the same as the decoding in the regular case, that is, we find some primitive $n$-th root of unity and then use it to find the rest and just evaluate the polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[X^{N/n}]/(X^N+1)$ at these roots.
But what's not written in the sparse packing is the encoding. How does that work exactly? The usual way is to (after rounding to integers and orthogonal projection to the image of the canonical embedding) just multiply the vector by the inverse of the Vandermonde matrix of the primitive roots and then use the result as a coefficient vector for the polynomial. But here this method doesn't seem to be working as is and the $X^{N/n}$ makes it confusing to figure out. Does anyone know how this works or has sources explaining it?
